# Url.Page returns current URL instead of mentioned

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Url.Page in ASP.NET Core doesn't returns the correct URL. As you can see in the image below it generate link to /identity/auth/register (which is current url) instead of /identity/auth/confrimemail

[image: code from register post method]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I need to use Url.Action, since ConfrimEmail is action and not page.